# Upgrading Server 2016 to 2019, getting Windows 10 error

Tags: windows-server-2019

I'm upgrading a server from 2016 standard to 2019 standard.  I choose to save settings etc, but then I get this message and the KB doesn't tell me anything worth while.

"Windows 10 setup 1809 build 10.0.17763.1. This version is not current. For more info, go to KB4464619."

Comment: Did you install that update?

Comment: What medium so you use? ISO downloaded from the VLSC?

Comment: I downloaded the ISO and burned it to DVD

Comment: ISO was downloaded from Microsoft.

Comment: [Here's the answer that worked for me](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/868fc6b7-2642-4766-ac48-75d46f883bc1/upgrading-server-2016-to-2019-getting-windows-10-error?forum=ws2019) Just turn off internet access on the machine that's being upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

#### Disconnect the network before attempting again

1. Stop the installation process.
2. Delete the `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT` folder
3. Disconnect the network cable or disable the Network interface
4. Re-try the installation process.